# Right margin after moving background with mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseevent

So, I'm moving my background perspective with `mousemove`.

The problem is the the right margin of the image after moving . Initially, everything is fine.

How to avoid that?

[image: White right margin :(]

**HTML-**

```
<div id="bg">
    <div class="container1" >
            <div class="row1">
                    <div class="col-md-12" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-duration="2600" data-aos-once="true"> 
                        <h1 class="title">Keeping track of your health. I`m a:</h1>
                    </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12" align="center" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="2600" data-aos-once="true" >
                                <a class="btn-link" href="/doctor-register"><button class="btn" type="button" type="submit" value="doctor">DOCTOR</button></a>
                                <a class="btn-link" href="/patient-register"> <button class="btn" type="button" type="submit" value="patient">PATIENT</button></a>
                                <a class="btn-link" href="/donor-register"><button class="btn" type="button" type="submit" value="donor">DONOR</button></a>
                        </div>
            </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
</div>
```

**CSS-**

```
#bg { 
height: 100vh;
background-image: url('../../../images/3.png'); /*  Background Image Link */   
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
}
```

**Javascript-**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bg").mousemove(function(e){
    var x = -(e.pageX + this.offsetLeft) / 65;
    var y = -(e.pageY + this.offsetTop) / 65;
    $('#bg').css("background-position", x + "px " + y + "px");
  });
});
```

Comment: I think it's because you're using `background-size: cover`, try using percent value instead, like `background-size: 130%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can made effect by extend image background and remove `background-position:center` ,(replace `background-size:cover` , by `background-size:120%;`)

See below Snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bg").mousemove(function(e) {
    var x = -(e.pageX + this.offsetLeft) / 40;
    var y = -(e.pageY + this.offsetTop) / 40;
    $('#bg').css("background-position", x + "px " + y + "px");
  });
});
```

```css
#bg {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/01/66/28/0166280c7713de4cc466aa3ca7052d11.jpg');
  /*  Background Image Link */
  background-size: 120%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="bg">
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="row1">
      <div class="col-md-12" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-duration="2600" data-aos-once="true">
        <h1 class="title">Keeping track of your health. I`m a:</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12" align="center" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="2600" data-aos-once="true">
        <a class="btn-link" href="/doctor-register"><button class="btn" type="button" type="submit" value="doctor">DOCTOR</button></a>
        <a class="btn-link" href="/patient-register"> <button class="btn" type="button" type="submit" value="patient">PATIENT</button></a>
        <a class="btn-link" href="/donor-register"><button class="btn" type="button" type="submit" value="donor">DONOR</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /container -->
</div>
```

Comment: You're Welcome :)